# Is it bad to create and use custom Deprecated and NeedsWork C# attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, attributes

I want to mark many of my C# functions as "deprecated" or "needs work".  My plan is to create customer attributes that I use to tag the functions.  I saw this question which seems to indicate that information only attributes will not effect performance:

[Is this use of attributes in .Net (C#) expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272005/is-this-use-of-attributes-in-net-c-expensive)

My question is whether this is a bad use for attributes.  Is there better way to mark code so that I can come back in phase 2 and either eliminate the code or rework it in some way?

P.S. I realize that there is an Obsolete attribute, but it results in far too many compiler warnings.  I want to be able to see the "real" compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like you want to create some sort of Project Management attributes for your classes.

I see project management as different than your code. If a feature is not 'done' right the first time, chances are it will be burried under other priorities and 'good enough' will cut it.

Of course there is always the [Task list comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) just add // TODO: and you will get it in your task list editor in visual studio if you do need reminders in your code.

I wouldn't go so far as to decorate classes with 'needfixing' attributes. If it's done it's done, if it's not it's not, if you need a reminder a todo should be enough.

Comment: I have a lot of functions in my domain layer that work just fine, but I'd like to come back and clean them up.  For example, I have functions that take an HttpContext as a parameter.  I think there's a separation of concerns issue there where my domain layer shouldn't be working with HttpContext objects.  Rebuilding my ASP.NET app in to ASP.NET MVC has really brought up a lot of separation of concerns issues for me.

My bigger point is that I have to get this done now, but I want to tag functions in some way.  You are probably right that I should use the //TODO: comments.

Comment: A TODO comment is more understandable if someone else was to pick up your code. I find that a custom attribute such as 'needsfixing' would be just too cryptic. If you can get your work done with TODO, I would go with that. Even better I would get it done now. Technical debt hardly ever gets prioritised over a functional requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I won't say that it's "bad" to mark code that needs work with attributes, but it may be overkill.  Have you considered [XML comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)?

Comment: I had planned on Attributes over XML comments because they are a little bit more lightweight to quickly enter and they are a little more searchable.  Ultimately, I think the //TODO: comments are probably more appropriate.

Comment: No need to explain, glad I could provide another option to consider.  Actually, the //TODO trick is pretty handy, I need to remember that for future projects.